# Iterating over async events, need to pass an object

Tags: java, android

I have the following problem:

I have implemented an API to my server returning objects, which is all fine and well. All the calls to the API starts an `AsyncTask`, and returns a result in a method. Problem is, at one point (I need this is bad coding, but disregard that for a minute) over a list of returned Events. These Events are returned from one `AsyncTask` call, and used for another `AsyncTask` call, and I need to pass the event I'm iterating over to the next API call as seen here:

```
api.retrieveEvents(new GetResponseCallback<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void onDataReceived(ArrayList<Event> list) {
            for (Event e : list) {
                api.retrieveReservationsForEvent(e, new GetResponseCallback<EventRegistration>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataReceived(ArrayList<EventRegistration> list) {
                        Log.d("We are in event", e.getEventName());
                    }
                });
```

Now obviously, Java won't allow you to use a local variable outside its classes scope, without it being declared final. That's obviously not gonna work here, and I can't assign the event to a field variable either, since that will just result in the final event I'm iterating over to be the one the `retrieveReservationsForEvent` call all the use. Any ideas of what to do?

retrieveReservationsForEvent looks like this:

```
public void retrieveReservationsForEvent(Event event, final GetResponseCallback<EventRegistration> callback) {
    final ArrayList<EventRegistration> eventRegistrations = new ArrayList<>();
    String restUrl = SERVER_NAME + REST_EVENTREGISTRATION + event.getId();
    new GetTask(restUrl, new RestTaskCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response) {
            try {
                // TODO probably throws an exception if there is only one attendant...
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject tempEventRegistrationJSON = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                    long dateInMillis = tempEventRegistrationJSON.getLong("timeOfArrival");
                    Date date = new Date(dateInMillis);

                    EventRegistration tempEventRegistration = new EventRegistration(tempEventRegistrationJSON.getInt("id"),
                            tempEventRegistrationJSON.getInt("eventNightId"), tempEventRegistrationJSON.getInt("guestId"),
                            date, tempEventRegistrationJSON.getInt("numberOfGuests"));
                    tempEventRegistration.setGuestName(tempEventRegistrationJSON.getString("guestName"));
                    tempEventRegistration.setGuestPhoneNumber(tempEventRegistrationJSON.getInt("phoneNumber"));
                    tempEventRegistration.setGuestMail("mail");

                    eventRegistrations.add(tempEventRegistration);

                    callback.onDataReceived(eventRegistrations);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).execute();
}
```

GetTask is merely doing a GET request, returning the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that changing it to:

```
for (final Event e : list) {
```

doesn't work? Does it give you an error during compilation?

Comment: Funny thing: ttis has seemed to work earlier. Then it stopped working; presumably because once that event is declared final, well, whatever we iterate over, won't ever be assigned to e after the first go around. No idea why it worked earlier though. Should it work? EDIT: No compilation errors, just unexpected runtime behavior.

Comment: Yeah, that specific part should be fine, at least. You should think of the e as being declared inside the loop, not outside of it. So you really have several e vars (scoped inside the loop), not just one.

Comment: Really? It seems it's using the last first retrieveReservationsForEvent's event argument in all of the retrieveReservationsForEvent call. I don't manipulate the event anywhere else. What gives?

Comment: The retrieveReservationsForEvent() method doesn't change the passed-in object in any way?

Comment: I've updated the original post with the code. The hell, why is the callback inside the for loop. Gosh darn it, that was the mistake! Thanks for your help. Turns out the final was the real deal, even though I misunderstood its use.